# If the Symmedian/Lemoine point of triangle $ABC$ lies on the Altitude from vertex $C$, show that either $BC = AC$ or angle $C = 90 ^\circ$.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

If the Symmedian/Lemoine point of triangle $ABC$ lies on the Altitude from vertex $C$, show that either $BC = AC$ or angle $C = 90^\circ$.

I have proved it going the other way. When given that $C$ is $90^\circ$, I can show that the Lemoine point lies on the altitude, but I cannot figure out how to go backward or incorporate the $BC = AC$ part.

I have tried using the median from vertex $C$, which I know is an isogonal conjugate of the symmedian from $C$. But then from there I don't know where to go.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried using the median from vertex C, which I know is a isogonal conjugate of the symmedian from C. But then from there I don't know where to go.

Comment: In this case you should include it in the question. It will make the question less likely to attract downvotes or be closed/flagged. In this community showing what you have tried so far is strongly encouraged.

Comment: I appreciate this, thank you. I will add it in.

Comment: @samcole: Giving your proof of the "other way" would be helpful, too, as it will show readers the kinds of results and techniques familiar to you. This can help people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level.

Comment: @Blue I added my proof the other way. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @sam cole  I have found a very nice solution of your problem. If you want to see it don't delete your topic.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg   Yea i didnt mean to do that. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

The coordinates of the symmedian point $X_6$ and
the foot of the altitude $H_c$
in terms of vertices $A(A_x,A_y),\ B(B_x,B_y),\ C(C_x,C_y)$ and side lengths $a,b,c$
can be found as
\begin{align} 
X_6&= \frac{a^2\,A+b^2\,B+c^2\,C}{a^2+b^2+c^2}
\tag{1}\label{1}
,\\
H_c&=
\tfrac12\,(A+B)+\frac{a^2-b^2}{2c^2}\,(A-B)
\tag{2}\label{2}
.
\end{align}

Condition $X_6\in CH_c$ is equivalent to

\begin{align}
\operatorname{Im}
\left(
\frac{H_c-C}{X_6-C}
\right)
&=0
\tag{3}\label{3}
.
\end{align}

Let $C=(0,0)$, then the condition \eqref{3} simplifies to

\begin{align}
(b^2-a^2)(a^2+b^2-c^2)(A_x B_y-A_y B_x)
&=0
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

which holds either if $a=b$,
or $c^2=a^2+b^2$.
The third option, $A_x B_y=A_y B_x$,
corresponds to the degenerate case,
when all the vertices of $\triangle ABC$
are collinear.

Answer (score 0):

Let $CM$, $CK$ and $CH$   be a median, a bisector and an altitude of $\Delta ABC$ respectively.

Since $CH$ is a symmedian, we obtain: $$\measuredangle KCM=\measuredangle KCH,$$ which gives:

$$\measuredangle ACM=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACB-\measuredangle KCM=\frac{1}{2}\measuredangle ACB-\measuredangle KCH=\measuredangle BCH=90^{\circ}-\measuredangle CBA,$$ which says $$\measuredangle ACM+\measuredangle CBA=90^{\circ}.$$

Now, let $\Phi$ be a circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$ and $CM\cap\Phi=\{C,D\}$.

Thus, $$\measuredangle CBD=\measuredangle CBA+\measuredangle ABD=\measuredangle CBA+\measuredangle ACD=90^{\circ},$$ which says that $CD$ is a diameter of the circle.

Now, if also $AB$ is a diameter of $\Phi$, so $\measuredangle ACB=90^{\circ},$ otherwise, $CD\perp AB$, which says $CB=CA$ and we are done!

Comment: Is it possible for you to post a picture to go along with this? I am confused on what point D is.

Comment: @sam cole  I used your picture. I don't know to draw in the net.

Comment: Where is D? In my post I cut off the top of the picture, so the triangle is ABC. I don't have a D in my picture.

Comment: @sam cole $D$ is a second intersection point of the line $CM$ with the circumcircle of  $\Delta ABC$. Just take $\Delta ABC$, a median $CM$ and draw the circumcircle of $\Delta ABC$. I am sure that you'll see it.

Comment: Oh duh, my bad. Last thing, I don't see where I showed angle BCM + angle CAB. = 90. Could you explain that part? If so, then I am done and I understand the whole thing. Thank you so much you have helped a lot.

Comment: @sam cole I fixed a typo. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: You didnt show how BCM + CAB = 90, or I am missing it.

Comment: @sam cole I'll write in another form.

Comment: Why do you know "otherwise, CD is perpendicular to AB"

Comment: @sam cole Because $M$ is a mid-point of the chord $AB$ , which is not a diameter and $CD$ is a diameter of the circle.